# Starting a localhost webserver in jenkins-ci (cloudbees)

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

My test require running an `index.html` file from localhost ant not as `file:///`. this means I need to start a local webserver and use it to present my website. all this from jenkins script in cloudbees. how and if this could be achieved?

thanks!

Comment: How do you do that outside of Jenkins? That's how you implement it in Jenkins as well. If you run into issues that are Jenkins specific, please let us know.

Comment: Out of jenkins I would probably run the server in another console instance

Comment: How about creating a background process? Don't forget to destroy it when you are done. Alternatively, have a webserver running on the same or different box and deploy to that box. Make sure that only one job is using this webserver at any given time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python to start a tiny HTTP server which will serve static files

```
mkdir /tmp/htdocs
cd /tmp/htdocs
echo index > index.html
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9090 &
sleep 5
curl -S http://localhost:9090/index.html
```

This can be launched in an `Execute shell` step.